# Safe way to upload GIF

Tags: php, image, security, gd, gif

I'm implementing image upload solution.

Now that everything works fine, I started thinking about security.
After researching much on internet, I found that safest way to upload image it recreate it.

For that I use GD Image Editor, which gets image size and resizes it to -1px from every side.

The problem which rose is that I cant recreate GIF image, as it becomes static (and ugly).

My question is, if anyone has done something and what options I have? Maybe some other solution to safely allow users to upload GIF imagies?

Comment: if it's a valid image, why do you want to manipulate it?

Comment: So its better to just check it with sizes right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and most important thing is to assign your own filename and extension to any uploaded image. Since your webserver decides on what to do with your file depending on it's extension, you should make damn sure it is '.gif'.
Renaming the whole file and not only it's extension ensures noone finds a ways break your extension safety and inject his own extension.

Never rely on any mime type sent to determine file type. Mime types can be manipulated and are not reliable. If you HAVE to check your file, use something like getimagesize(). But again, this is not necessary if you set the filename and extension anyways.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

You should also ensure file size is not to large to avoid your server running out of space.

Ensuring a login before uploading and only allowing a reasonable number of uploads per user is also a nice safety agains running out of space.

So, in short:

- Set filename and extension
- Dont rely on sent filename
- Dont rely on sent mime type
- check maximum filesize
- ensure user can not spam files

Comment: Oh, and you might also want to check TTP. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ttp

Comment: thanks, getImageSize makes sense, if it has a size then its an image ) I dont get the mime type part. I mean I have an idea how this can work, can you validate it? For example when somebody uploads an image I can check if this ends with .gif or .jpg, then make my own name and in the end (in case of .gif) append .gif. or is there any fuction (in GD for instance) to get the correct type?

Comment: No. You should do exactly that. You CAN also check `imageinfo` part of getimagesize(), but you should not rely on anything else, especially not the mime part of $_FILES.

Comment: got that, thanks, this way is even simpler. I just didnt get the TTP )) sounds funny but I cant find anything on internet. do you mean php execution time? like to not eat CPU

Comment: I included a link on what TTP is :)

Comment: yeah but as for not native english speaker - I HATE URBAN DICTINARY :D i mean I didn't get it

Comment: It means you might think if users could upload unsuitable content via this function without anyone checking file before they go public.

Comment: Hello again, while developing (on wordpress) I found that WP has built in function for such situatuions, I want to know if I can trust this function, you know a little bit of regEx 
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L1852

Comment: You should create a new question specific to this Wordpress issue then.